# Issue in for and foreach - distinguish

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I am creating a comma separated list using foreach and for. Below is the code...

```
$timeofdaylist = "";
foreach($_POST['timeofday'] as $key => $value)
{
    if($timeofdaylist == "")
    {
        $timeofdaylist = "'".$value."'";
    }
    else
    {
        $timeofdaylist .= ",'".$value."'";
    }               
}
echo $timeofdaylist;
```

The above code gives me a comma separated list like this : 'AM','PM'

Here my first condition `$timeofdaylist == ""` is working properly as I expected.

And now another piece of code

```
$timeofdaylist = "";
var_dump($timeofdaylist);
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['timeofday']);$i++) {          
    if($timeofdaylist == "") {
        $timeofdaylist = "'".$_POST['timeofday'][$i]."'";
    } else {
        $timeofdaylist = ",'".$_POST['timeofday'][$i]."'";
    }       
}
echo $timeofdaylist;
```

The above code only prints the last value, like this : ,'PM'

I have var_dumped timeofdaylist and checked before my first condition of `$timeofdaylist == ""`. It shows length=0.

Can anyone distinguish the difference between above two pieces of code?
TIA

Comment: what's the structure of `$_POST['timeofday']`?

Comment: If you want to make a concatenated string out of an array, you can use [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) as well. `$timeofdaylist = "'" . implode("', '", $_POST['timeofday']) . "'";`. Much cleaner than all those `for`s. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you reset variable `$timeofdaylist` in each iteration,
so it only contains the last value of the array

Your first example,

`$timeofdaylist .= ",'".$value."'";` = concatenate the string

So, I guess

```
$timeofdaylist .= ",'".$_POST['timeofday'][$i]."'";
```

Assuming typo is the cause of the problem ...

Comment: +1 you typed it faster than me. "<-- concatenate the string" that text should be a comment ;) Also be explicit in that the difference is the missing concatenation operator: '.'